# Android Navigation Component - How to navigate to other startDestination in nested graph

Tags: android, android-jetpack

I have issue with Navigation Component. I have four fragments, look like the picture below.

How to navigate from fragment Home to fragment B?

Please help me,
Thanks.

Picture:

[image: Picture]

Comment: What type of thing are nav_main and nav_nested -- activities? Layouts?

Comment: nav_main, nav_nested are navigation (res/navigation/nav_main.xml)

Comment: Please, help me

Comment: Until now, I still have no solution!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to associate a deep link to the `Frg B` in the `nav_nested`.

```
<deepLink app:uri="myApp://myFragmentB" />
```

And then navigate to it:

```
findNavController().navigate(Uri.parse("myApp://myFragmentB"))
```